# React - How to push array in object using useState

Tags: reactjs

I'm building chat app using ReactJS, NestJS, Socket.io .

And it's multi channel using rooms in socket.io

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState({
        ReactJS: [],
        NestJS: [],
        Typescript: [],
        MySQL: [],
        Neo4j: [],
        Redis: [],
        ELK: [],
        Docker: [],
        Kubernetes: [],
        AWS: [],
        SocketIO: [],
    });
```

This is array with useState for pushing message.

## Question

```
messages['ReactJS'].push(someMessage);
```

How useState push element to array inside object?

Comment: messages contains no `roomname` property.

Comment: It is just example.

Comment: @gman I believe it is intended to be a dynamic key.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding you.
I'm not native english speaker.

Comment: @Drew Reese, You can't push something into a non-existent array. And further the state is of APIs but 'roomname' is not an API. It's not a reasonable question and you should vote to close for more details. Answering will not actually help this user. BTW: your answers will fail with `TypeError: messages[roomKey] is not iterable`.

Comment: @gman Ok, sure. You make assumptions about what "roomname" literally means, I made assumptions about key always being existent keys in state. I amended my solution with a pattern I use to handle dynamic keys that are not known ahead of time. This should handle any "iterable" issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the state

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState({
  ReactJS: [],
  NestJS: [],
  Typescript: [],
  MySQL: [],
  Neo4j: [],
  Redis: [],
  ELK: [],
  Docker: [],
  Kubernetes: [],
  AWS: [],
  SocketIO: [],
});
```

Then the following is a way to update a specific room via a `roomKey` identifier nested in the state object. In React when you update state you ***must*** always return a new object reference, and this includes any nested state/properties that are being updated. [array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) mutates the original array, it doesn't create a new array reference for React purposes.

```
setMessages(messages => ({
  ...messages, // <-- shallow copy state
  // copy existing nested state array into new array and append new element
  [roomKey]: [...messages[roomKey], newMessage],
}));
```

An alternative to the array literal is to use [array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), which does return a new array.

```
setMessages(messages => ({
  ...messages, // <-- shallow copy state
  // copy existing nested state array into new array and append new element
  [roomKey]: messages[roomKey].concat(newMessage),
}));
```

**Note:** This assumes your `roomKey` variable will reference one of the keys actually defined in your state. If you use an unspecified key then `messages[unknownKey]` will be undefined. In this case, if you've truly dynamic keys, then you can provide a fallback value to spread into state.

```
setMessages(messages => ({
  ...messages, // <-- shallow copy state
  // copy existing nested state array into new array and append new element
  [roomKey]: [
    ...messages[roomKey] || [], // <-- provide fallback
    newMessage,
  ],
}));
```

Comment: Thanks. But do you know how set type in useState? 
I'm using typescript and code above show error because of type.

Comment: You need to make an interface. You can do useState<any>({
  ReactJS: [],
  NestJS: [],
  Typescript: [],
  MySQL: [],
  Neo4j: [],
  Redis: [],
  ELK: [],
  Docker: [],
  Kubernetes: [],
  AWS: [],
  SocketIO: [],
}) to get around it

Comment: @camlyport Unfortunately no, I'm not very familiar with Typescript. You'll need some type/interface definition, but other than that I'm a bit of a fish out of water. Perhaps you should refine your question and provide more of your requirements. Try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: that's right. but I guess, this will give error when spreading `[...message[roomkey], newMessage]` as  `message[roomkey]` will return undefined initially when there is no `roomKey` key available in the object. Am I right??

Comment: @Rajiv If the keys used are the ones already in state, then all those state values are defined, truthy, values, i.e. an empty array to copy from and add to. I added an edit to handle unknown keys, essentially provide a fallback value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install some additional utilities here are some other way to do it

### [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)

```
rootPath = 'ReactJS'
const newArray = R.append(someMessage, messages[rootPath])
const newMessages = R.assocPath([rootPath], newArray, messages);
setMessages(newMessages)

// combined
const rootPath = 'ReactJS'
setMessages(
    R.assocPath(
        [rootPath],
        R.append(
            someMessage,
            messages[rootPath]
        ),
        messages
    )
)
```

### [Immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/)

```
import produce from 'immer'

const rootPath = 'ReactJS'
const newMessages = produce(messages, draftState => {
    draftState[rootPath].push = someMessage
})

setMessages(newMessages)

// combined
import p from 'immer'

const rootPath = 'ReactJS'
setMessages(p(messages, draft => {
    draft[rootPath].push = someMessage
}))
```